# Transforming linear acceleration data of IMU to linear velocity data

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
How to transform linear accelerating data of IMU to linear velocity data? I want to obtain linear x and y velocity value from IMU. How can ı do this? Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279067/transforming-linear-acceleration-data-of-imu-to-linear-velocity-data/) by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2018-01-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-07**:
Integrate. Acceleration is the derivative of velocity. So, to get to velocity from acceleration you need to integrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming the x and y axes of your IMU are aligned with your robot and you want the x and y velocities with respect to the robot:

```
delta_t = time between accelerometer readings

loop:
velocity_x += (accel_x * delta_t) 
velocity_y += (accel_y * delta_t)
```

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2018-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2018-01-08**:
thank you sir

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-08**:
Just keep in mind that by integrating the error will grow to be quite large over time.